# Count the number of full weekends worked (Sat&Sun) in an excel shift-work roster for each staff member over the current calendar year

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel rostering spreadsheet for shift workers and need to count the number of full weekends rostered (Sat&Sun) on/off for each staff member over the current calendar year.

I have tried several formulae, tried named ranges, countif, countifs etc. but am having problems counting identical values in two consecutive columns (days) in the same row i.e. Saturday and Sunday. Single day counts (such as number of Sundays worked) is no problem but I'm stumped with how to calculate the number of weekends when both days are rest-days, for example

The following works well for the number of single Rest Days (RD) falling on a Sunday but I need to determine the number of weekends in which both days(sat & Sun) are Rest Days.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(ROSTER!$M$17:$PM$17,"Sun",ROSTER!M28:PM28,{"RD"}))
```

[image: Sample Data]

The above is a small sample taken from a worksheet that contains a complete year's roster. Each roster is a two week block,starting on Sunday, with a column titled "RDFN" between the Sat and Sun at the end and beginning of the next fortnight.

Comment: Can you please provide some screenshot of your original table, or make a sample table use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGOzA.png

Comment: Hi I just added a link to a screenshot of a subset of the table in question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Edit 2**

As confirmed you want to count the number of weekends where **both Sat and Sun are RD** (Rest Day) in a given time frame.

I have revised my **SUMPRODUCT** formula (which works as **COUNTIF** in this case) to find the result for **Jane**. Simply drag it down to apply to other employees:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B5:AH5&C5:AI5)="RDRD")*((B$2:AH$2&C$2:AI$2)="SatSun"))+SUMPRODUCT(((B5:AH5&E5:AK5)="RDRD")*((B$2:AH$2&E$2:AK$2)="SatSun"))
```

This formula is using **two** SUMPRODUCT formula and adding the results from the two. Both SUMPRODUCT formula followed the same logic.

> **It will work in the case you have two columns between each fortnight, and it is actually slightly shorter than my previous
>   solution**.

Let's take **Jane**'s data for example. Imagine you have inserted four helper rows.

The formulas in the first helper row are `B$2&C$2`, `C$2&D$2`, and so on so forth till `AF2&AG2`, which represents **SunMon**, **MonTue**, **TueWed**, etc.

The formulas in the second helper row are `B5&C5`, `C5&D5`, and so on so forth till `AF5&AG5`, which represents **RD8 M**, **8 M14 A**, **14 A14 A**, etc.

So the first SUMPRODUCT formula is counting the number of **RDRD** in the second helper row when the corresponding position in the first helper row is returning **SatSun**.

```
First Part =SUMPRODUCT(((B5:AH5&C5:AI5)="RDRD")*((B$2:AH$2&C$2:AI$2)="SatSun"))
```

However the above formula is not working in situation where the last **Sat** of the first fortnight and the first **Sun** of the following fortnight are both **RD** because there are two columns in between which will not return **RDRD** in the second helper row so the match will fail.

To overcome the problem, I have to use a second SUMPRODUCT formula with the help from another two imaginary helper rows.

The formulas in the third helper row are `B$2&E$2`, `C$2&F$2`, and so on so forth till `AF$2&AI$2`, which represents **SunWed**, **MonThu**, **TueFri**, etc.

The formulas in the forth helper row are `B5&E5`, `C5&F5`, and so on so forth till `AF5&AI5`, which represents **RD14 A**, **8 M9 M**, **14 A6 M**, etc.

The second SUMPRODUCT formula is also counting **RDRD** in the forth helper row when the corresponding position in the third helper row is returning **SatSun**.

```
Second Part =SUMPRODUCT(((B5:AH5&E5:AK5)="RDRD")*((B$2:AH$2&E$2:AK$2)="SatSun"))
```

Adding the results from both parts will give you the total number of weekends where both Sat and Sun are RD as shown below:

[image: SUMPRODUCT Example]

Comment: Thanks for this excellent solution Terry. It goes very close to solving my problem. One issue is that the value in the "RD/FN" columns is not always =4, also there is an additional column next to this column between the end/start of each fortnight that I omitted from the example for simplicity sake; a mistake with hindsight. I thought the use of wildcards may get around this using your formula but I gather SUMPRODUCT doesn't support wildcards. I'll attach an example with this additional column if you have time to look. Either way, thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Dicko may I know if the values in RD/FN column is hard-coded or is it determined by a formula? If it is hard-coded what are the variations and when will such variation appear? If it is determined by a formula what is the formula? Also what is the purpose of having two columns in between each fortnight? If they can be removed it will shorten my answer. If not please respond to my above queries with a new sample data screen-shot so I can amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Terry, both RD/FN and RDWE are determined by formulae:

Comment: @Dicko please let me know the formula for each column, and did you manually inserted these columns to the original time sheet? What are the purposes of showing these two columns in between the fortnights data? Are they removable?

Comment: RD/FN: COUNTIF(B52:O5,"RD")

Comment: RDWE (using R1C1 format): COUNTIF(RC[-15], "RD")+COUNTIF(RC[-9], "RD")+COUNTIF(RC[-8], "RD")+COUNTIF(RC[-2], "RD")  Removing these columns is not really feasible as I have inherited this workbook from a previous staff member and the rostering officer requires the data to look like this. I am trying to get rid of several background working sheets used by the original developer.Thanks for your help, have to stop for the night now :-)

Comment: @Dicko please see my updated solution which used the same logic as my previous one but it is a better one as it only looked at the relevant ranges in the second part, and also solved your issue of having two columns in between the data.

Comment: @Dicko good to know it worked. If my answer is working for you, could you please mark it as an accepted solution by clicking the tick mark under the down vote button? No fuss :)